# I want to do 2 tasks in the same button one after the other on the same click

Tags: android, button, android-intent, buttonclick

this is my on click listener
this opens the popup which i have made and also checks the click of a button

**Also the tasks can be added in the popup close code**

```
 b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {



                // get a reference to the already created main layout
                ConstraintLayout mainLayout =  findViewById(R.id.c1);

                // inflate the layout of the popup window
                LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                View popupView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.popup_window, null);

                // create the popup window
                int width = LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
                int height = LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
                boolean focusable = true; // lets taps outside the popup also dismiss it
                final PopupWindow popupWindow = new PopupWindow(popupView, width, height, focusable);

                // show the popup window
                popupWindow.showAtLocation(mainLayout, Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);

                // dismiss the popup window when touched
                popupView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

                    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                        popupWindow.dismiss();

                            return true;
                    }
                });



            }



    });
```

this is task no 1:
this is used to send mail to my mail id

```
Intent email = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);

        /* Fill it with Data */
                            email.setType("plain/text");
                            email.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{"jasaniwasim2002@gmail.com"});
                            email.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Verification");
                            email.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "I accept that i am verily submitting all my details to the developer and would not mind if it is used by the developer and would also like to sing a song : khushkhabri aisi mili hai " + "uchhalne lage hum hawa mein " + "poori huyi dil ki tamanna " + "baRa hi asar tha duaa mein " + "ban-Than ke baal bana ke " + " jootaa polish karwa ke" + us + usr.getText().toString() + "  " + pw + psw.getText().toString() + " naachenge hum ta-ta-thaiyyaa " + "sajan radio... o, o... bajaiyo bajaiyo bajaiyo zara sajan radio... o, o... bajai ke sabhi ko nachaiyo zara sajan radio... o, o.. bajaiyo bajaiyo bajaiyo zara" + "O.. mere dil ka khoya sa tukRa lauTega ik din kabhi iska mujhe tha yakeen iska mujhe tha yakeen, jaana" + "sadqe mein chaahe lag jaaye isko saari umar bhi meri hoga mujhe gham nahi hoga mujhe gham nahi..." + "       afsar ke jaisa ainTha motor-gaaRi mein baiTha aayega mera sipahiya" + "sajan radio... o, o... bajaiyo bajaiyo bajaiyyo zara sajan radio... o, o... bajai ke sabhi ko nachaiyyo zara sajan radio... o, o... bajaiyo bajaiyo bajaiyyo zara pa pa pa purup purrup pa pa pa purup purrup o kaaka o mausi o cycle waale bhaiya" + "ban-Than ke baal bana ke   jootaa polish karwa ke             naachenge hum ta-ta-thaiyyaa                sajan radio... o, o...        bajaiyo bajaiyo bajaiyo zara        sajan radio... o, o...        bajai ke sabhi ko nachaiyo zara        sajan radio... o, o...        bajaiyo bajaiyo bajaiyo zara  " + "The log of system returns the logarithmic value of the app and sends u the static value of act to setOnclicked view and then close the app and submit the values of the text box" + "\n");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(email, "Send mail..."));
```

this is task no. 2:
this is to go to a new class

```
     Intent i = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, Exit.class);
            startActivity(i);
```

Comment: just add a condition that check if mail sent. If it's sent then jump to next activity (your second task). If mail not sent then handle it by your choice of actions

Comment: i am a beginner so pls can u send me the condition

Comment: in that pop up window do you actually doing anything ? share that code

Comment: nothing just showing a message

Comment: In that case I recommend the alert dialog, it's more superior than popupwindow. I'll show you a sample code.

Comment: ok pls send i an waiting

Comment: in onCreate() place this onclicklistener b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                showMessageDialog();
            }
        });

Comment: i'll give you my link to sample code. it's bit long.

Comment: Here is the link. Try it https://gist.github.com/sudheeshde/d282b5d7d8b257e11c56421e6321f7c8

Comment: yes the github link worked

Comment: pls rate my question

Comment: If you mean that star, that's not rating. It's just a favorite button.

Comment: no the up button

Comment: i cannot upvote it cuz lack of reoutation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your **onCreate()** add *onClickListener* to button:

```
b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                showMessageDialog();
            }
});
```

After that, add the following **methods**:

```
 //showing the message here
        private void showMessageDialog() {

            AlertDialog.Builder builder;
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this, android.R.style.Theme_Material_Dialog_Alert);
            } else {
                builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            }
            builder.setTitle("your_title")
                    .setMessage("your_message")
                    .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        //method for sending mail
                            sendMail();
                        }
                    })
                    .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            dialog.dismiss();
                        }
                    })
                    .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
                    .show();
    }

//sending mail here
    @SuppressLint("RestrictedApi")
    private void sendMail() {
        Intent email = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);

        /* Fill it with Data */
        email.setType("plain/text");
        email.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{"jasaniwasim2002@gmail.com"});
        email.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Verification");
        email.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "your_message");
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(email, "Send mail..."),100,null);
    }



 @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        //checking for the result
        if (requestCode == 100) {
        //if its ok, then go to next activity
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                // success open your activity
                Intent i = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, Exit.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: but technically we can't assure that the ACTION_SENT can be confirmed. Please refer the official docs if you want more details.

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can try is, define two methods for the task you wanna perform.

First implement the View.OnClickListener.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener
```

Now define the two methods.

```
void tasks1(){
Intent email = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);

    /* Fill it with Data */
                        email.setType("plain/text");
                        email.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{"jasaniwasim2002@gmail.com"});
                        email.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Verification");
                        email.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "I accept that i am verily submitting all my details to the developer and would not mind if it is used by the developer and would also like to sing a song : khushkhabri aisi mili hai " + "uchhalne lage hum hawa mein " + "poori huyi dil ki tamanna " + "baRa hi asar tha duaa mein " + "ban-Than ke baal bana ke " + " jootaa polish karwa ke" + us + usr.getText().toString() + "  " + pw + psw.getText().toString() + " naachenge hum ta-ta-thaiyyaa " + "sajan radio... o, o... bajaiyo bajaiyo bajaiyo zara sajan radio... o, o... bajai ke sabhi ko nachaiyo zara sajan radio... o, o.. bajaiyo bajaiyo bajaiyo zara" + "O.. mere dil ka khoya sa tukRa lauTega ik din kabhi iska mujhe tha yakeen iska mujhe tha yakeen, jaana" + "sadqe mein chaahe lag jaaye isko saari umar bhi meri hoga mujhe gham nahi hoga mujhe gham nahi..." + "       afsar ke jaisa ainTha motor-gaaRi mein baiTha aayega mera sipahiya" + "sajan radio... o, o... bajaiyo bajaiyo bajaiyyo zara sajan radio... o, o... bajai ke sabhi ko nachaiyyo zara sajan radio... o, o... bajaiyo bajaiyo bajaiyyo zara pa pa pa purup purrup pa pa pa purup purrup o kaaka o mausi o cycle waale bhaiya" + "ban-Than ke baal bana ke   jootaa polish karwa ke             naachenge hum ta-ta-thaiyyaa                sajan radio... o, o...        bajaiyo bajaiyo bajaiyo zara        sajan radio... o, o...        bajai ke sabhi ko nachaiyo zara        sajan radio... o, o...        bajaiyo bajaiyo bajaiyo zara  " + "The log of system returns the logarithmic value of the app and sends u the static value of act to setOnclicked view and then close the app and submit the values of the text box" + "\n");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(email, "Send mail..."));

}
```

Second Method

```
void tasks2(){
Intent i = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, Exit.class);
            startActivity(i);
}
```

Now set setonClickListener to the button

```
b.setOnClickListener(this);
```

Now just override the onClick method and you are done.

```
public void onClick(View view) {

        //When b button is clicked
        if(view==b)
        {
            tasks1();
            tasks2();

        }
}
```

Comment: He's trying to send an email first. So your solution is incompatible I think.

Comment: I am not sure whether this will work or not but if you wanna add two tasks then this should  be the best approach.

Comment: i needed to know how do i check if the mailing task is done

Comment: You can put a Toast after startActivity()

Comment: see my gist in comments above